# Eigenvalues of sum of self-adjoint operators.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\varphi$ and $\psi$ be two self-adjoint operators in the Euclidean space $\mathbb{E}$ and their eigenvalues belong to intervals $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ respectively. Prove that eigenvalues of $\varphi + \psi$ belong to the interval $[a+b, c+d]$.

I got stuck with this task. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these operators are self-adjoint we know that their eigenvalues are the critical points of the associated [Rayleigh quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient), i.e. the eigenvalues of $\varphi$, resp. $\psi$ are the critical points of 
$$R_{\varphi}(x)= \frac{\langle \varphi x,x\rangle}{\langle x,x\rangle} \qquad \text{resp.} \qquad R_{\psi}(x)= \frac{\langle \psi x,x\rangle}{\langle x,x\rangle}$$
In particular, by assumption you have
$$ a\leq R_{\varphi}(x) \leq b \qquad \text{and} \qquad c\leq R_{\psi}(x) \leq d\qquad \forall x \in \mathbb E\setminus\{0\}.$$ 
Now, note that
$$ R_{\varphi+\psi}(x)= R_{\varphi}(x) +R_{\psi}(x) \qquad \forall x \in \mathbb E\setminus\{0\},$$
and so 
$$ a+c \leq R_{\varphi+\psi}(x) \leq b+d \qquad \forall x \in \mathbb E\setminus\{0\}$$
which proves the claim.

Comment: this explaination is very easy. Thank you :)

Comment: @Okaerinasai You're welcome :).